# Can't check ArchiveStatus for mailbox

Tags: if-statement, automation, office365, powershell-3.0, system-administration

I am building a script that'll check if `ArchiveStatus` for an Office 365 mailbox is active or not. I am able to pull the data, but my `if`/`else` statement doesn't seem to work. This is what I have so far:

```
$Data = Get-Mailbox -Identity "MailboxName" | ft name,*Archive*
$Data

if ($_.ArchiveStatus -eq $true) {
  Write-Host "Archive Enabled"
} else{
  Write-Host "Archiving Disabled"
}
```

No matter what mailbox I search up, the result is always "Archiving Disabled" even if the console shows user enabled.

Answer (score 0):

The [current object variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx) (`$_`) is only available in a pipeline context. Your `if` statement is outside a pipeline, so `$_` doesn't exist, meaning that `$_.ArchiveStatus` evaluates to `$null`, which is interpreted as `$false` in the comparison.

Change this:

```
$Data = Get-Mailbox -Identity "MailboxName" | ft name,*Archive*
$Data

if ($_.ArchiveStatus -eq $true) {
  Write-Host "Archive Enabled"
} else {
  Write-Host "Archiving Disabled"
}
```

into this:

```
$Data = Get-Mailbox -Identity "MailboxName"
$Data | ft name,*Archive*

if ($Data.ArchiveStatus -eq $true) {
  Write-Host "Archive Enabled"
} else {
  Write-Host "Archiving Disabled"
}
```

and the problem should disappear.

Comment: Thanks @Ansgar for the response however I am still getting the Disabled message for every user.  Perhaps I need to do something else?

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to figure it out with help from @Ansgar Wiechers. The -eq $true wasn't working because it was either Active or None.  When i created the variable for this it worked.  The working code is below:

```
$Data = Get-Mailbox -Identity "MailboxName"
$Data | ft name, ArchiveStatus
$Status = "Active"

if($Data.ArchiveStatus -eq $Status) {
Write-Host "Archive Enabled"
} Else {
Write-Host "Archiving Disabled"
}
```

Thank you for your help!!